# rc.local, call commands sequentially (one after finishing the other)

Tags: boot, rc.local

I was expecting that in `rc.local`, If say I call program `P1` in one line and then `P2` in the following line, `P2` would only be executed after `P1` (on which it depends for successful execution). This is the behavior in bash scripts. However, after booting my machine, `P2` was not completed. So my guess is that all commands written in `rc.local` are run in parallel and `P1` did not finish before the execution of `P2`. I guess this behavior makes sense for daemons...

If it's in parallel, I could just solve this by using the `&&` operator or creating a wrapper script. Still, I would like to confirm the behavior:

**In `rc.local`, commands in new lines are executed sequentially or in parallel?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines from `rc.local` are not executed in parallel.  It will be executed in the same order like any other bash script.

Don't guess why `P2` didn't run, find out for sure by logging its output.  For example:

```
P1 > /tmp/P1.startup 2>&1
P2 > /tmp/P2.startup 2>&1
```

If `P1` has to complete successfully before `P2` runs then you will need to set an if true statement.  One of these will work:

```
P1 && \
P2
```

Or

```
P1
test $? -eq 0 && P2
```

Or

```
P1
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
  P2
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and complete answer. I guess you meant in the first option `&&` ? -- Thanks! ;)